# How to place Component to the right of another Component

Tags: html, css

I learn som React and go through [this tutorial](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6517/react-router-tutorial) and I read for hours and dont understand if I wanted the `Home`, `Contact` and `About` Component in the tutorial to be place horizontal instead of vertical

This is what it looks like:

```
Welcome to React Router Tutorial
Home    
Contact     
About
```

What I want is

```
Welcome to React Router Tutorial  
Home Contact About
```

From the tutorial code here is the App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
        <div>
          <h2>Welcome to React Router Tutorial</h2>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> Home </Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/contact'} className="nav-link">Contact</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/about'} className="nav-link">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          <hr />
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
              <Route path='/about' component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `reactjs` question, but a `html` / `css` question.

Try applying this to all `li` elements:

```
<li style={{display: "inline-block"}}> ... </li>
```

When an element is displayed as `inline-block`, the element isn't pushed underneath the previous element, but instead positioned to the right.

There are many different solutions to horizontal positioning including tables, flexbox and more.

Answer (score 0):

it a `css` problem , not `reactjs` - here is a guide of placing elements on the page [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `CSS`,

```
ul{
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 10px;
}

ul li:first-child{
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x6bats)